# I am using a bootstrap navbar on my site and it acts differently on index page compared to the other pages

Tags: html, css, web, navigation, navbar

It is especially noticeable on mobile devices when the menu shrinks and the hamburger menu is in place

The margins seem to change and the spacing between the li reduces

www.thekentandsurrey.com/wip/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your index.html, you are calling the bootstrap.min.css in your header, but I don't see it on the other pages? This could be why the padding differs on different pages. Please verify if this was the issue.

Comment: Thank you, spot on. That was left from me trying something out

Comment: Awesome, great I was able to help you!